# How do you rotate a video from a URL in Swift?

Tags: swift, video, rotation, avassetwriter, avasset

I have my AVAssetWriter's completion handler create an exporter after it has finished writing so that the video can present itself in a player so the user can save it if they wish. That is all well and good, but I'd like to alter the written video and simply rotate it after it has finished writing.

The answers I've found to this varies from rotating the video as it's recording or deprecated old Objective-C ways that don't apply anymore.

My completion handler and exporter looks something like this. The exporter knows the outputFileType so I thought I'd be able to rotate the video there:

```
    assetWriter?.finishWriting(completionHandler: {[unowned self] () -> Void in

        let firstAsset = AVURLAsset(url: self.movieURL() as URL)

        guard let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: firstAsset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality) else { return }
        exporter.outputURL = self.movieURL() as URL
        exporter.outputFileType = AVFileType.mov

        exporter.exportAsynchronously() {
            DispatchQueue.main.async(){ 
// below here is where another class is presented with the 
// video URL to display in a player with the option to save
```

Comment: I have done video rotating , you can find answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53631353/solved-video-rotation-ios-swift-4-0